# Salvar cookies no Selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

Estou desenvolvendo uma automação em Selenium C# para entrar no Facebook e fazer umas operações, porém a cada login ele me pede a verificação de conta.

Existe uma forma que possa salvar as autenticações como um navegador comum para cada vez que executar não peça mais?

```
        public void Login(ref ModelSession<Browser> refLoginSession, ModelSession<Browser> session)
        {
            var browser = session.Session.Driver;

            string usuario = "emailusuario";
            string senha = "senha";

            browser.Url = "https://www.intern.facebook.com/help/contact/290640558131181";
            browser.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys(usuario);
            browser.FindElement(By.Id("pass")).SendKeys(senha);
            browser.FindElement(By.Id("loginbutton")).ClickJs();
         }
```

Comment: Pode ser útil: https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: ta usando que browser?

Comment: @Tmilitino Chrome man